# problems with rowspan while generating a PDF using iText

Tags: itext

Below is my sample application where I am getting an error on line 
Add2CellRow(table, "Age", 1, "Gender", 2);

I think the rowspan value is creating the issue as the next line is not building.

Can someone help on the same?

The code is for Arabic Culture so need to set

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");

private static void Add3CellRow(PdfPTable table, string cell1Value, string cell2Value, int rowspan, string imgPath) 
{

    PdfPCell new1Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell1Value, tableFont));
    new1Cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    new1Cell.MinimumHeight = 25f;
    new1Cell.Padding = 6f;
    table.AddCell(new1Cell);

    PdfPCell new2Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell2Value, tableFont));
    new2Cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    new2Cell.MinimumHeight = 25f;
    new2Cell.Padding = 6f;
    new2Cell.Colspan = 2;
    table.AddCell(new2Cell);

    PdfPCell new3Cell = null;

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imgPath))
    {
        Image img = Image.GetInstance(imgPath);
        img.ScaleToFit(150, 150);
        new3Cell = new PdfPCell(img);
    }
    else
    {
        new3Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.Empty));
    }

    new3Cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    new3Cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    new3Cell.MinimumHeight = 25f;
    new3Cell.Rowspan = rowspan;
    new3Cell.Colspan = 2;
    new3Cell.Padding = 6f;
    table.AddCell(new3Cell);
}             

private static void Add2CellRow(PdfPTable table, string cell1Value, int colspanCell1, string cell2Value, int colspanCell2 = 2)
{
    PdfPCell new1Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell1Value, tableFont));
    new1Cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    new1Cell.MinimumHeight = 25f;
    new1Cell.Colspan = colspanCell1;
    table.AddCell(new1Cell);

    PdfPCell new2Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell2Value, tableFont));
    new2Cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    new2Cell.Colspan = colspanCell2;
    new2Cell.MinimumHeight = 25f;
    new2Cell.Padding = 6f;
    table.AddCell(new2Cell);
}

public static MemoryStream Generate()
{                        
    var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 90, 110);

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);            

    doc.Open();

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);

    table.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;


    table.WidthPercentage = 89.5f;
    table.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    table.DefaultCell.Padding = 6f;
    table.DefaultCell.UseAscender = true;
    table.DefaultCell.UseDescender = true;

    Add3CellRow(table,"Name","Harshit Verma",4,"");            
    Add2CellRow(table, "Age", 1, "Gender", 2);
    Add2CellRow(table, "Age", 1, "Gender", 2);
    Add2CellRow(table, "Age", 1, "Gender", 2);

    table.SplitLate = false;

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("");
    doc.Add(p);
    table.SpacingBefore = 30f;
    doc.Add(table);

    writer.CloseStream = false;
    doc.Close();
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return memoryStream;
}
```

Comment: There's lots of row and column spans which makes my head hurt but I was finally able to reproduce your issue. When the table is operating in `LTR` mode everything works correctly, however when switching over to `RTL` mode I get the `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` exception from iTextSharp 5.5.5.0 (the only one I have locally).

Comment: I am getting the same problem Chris. In RTL too if you remove the rowsapn and create the PDF it is working fine.

Comment: That looks like something that should be posted to [JIRA](https://jira.itextsupport.com/) rather than to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Bruno Not a member. Cant login.

Comment: @Nikita It's for customers only. Ask your project manager to find out if you're a customer. If you're using iText in a commercial context (which you seem to be doing), you should be. In that case, up to three of your colleagues have a login.

Comment: @Bruno I'll check and let you know accordingly